# Include html file into another html file

Tags: html

Can someone guide me how to include html file with an html file. I have been trying to embed my file within object tags but to no avail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_iframe.asp) tag.
Another option is to used Server Side inclusion using SHTML, this require that the web server support it, see [Server Side Includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes)

Comment: Right! I remeber this one, it exists for years, I used it when I used SSI in late nineties and it has great explanation

Comment: the  boutell.com link basically says it all.

Answer (score 1):

You are quite limited in HTML. You can use [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) tag but it's the same type of embedding as embedding of flash in html pages.

OT: It would be quite easy in PHP. Can you use it? Or do you need static web page?

Comment: I am unsure whether server side includes can be used in static html pages at all. I have been trying to do it for quite some time but to no avail. Here's what I have been trying to to my html file which resides within the root of my web. 

<div>
    <!--#include virtual="/HtmlObjects/DeliveryEstimator.htm"-->
</div>

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know about this possibility. There are dynamic html pages and static html pages. I was asking to know what are your limitations. For example, if you want to create a static html in order to burn them on CD/DVD then it is better in my opinion to write a simple script in powershell/bash to do those includes for you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you perhaps use Javascript to dynamically load it in?

Answer (score 0):

You can have it loaded via JQuery as shown here: [Include another HTML file in a HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file)

a.html:

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function{
      $("#includedContent").load("b.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="includedContent"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

b.html:

```
<p> This is my include file </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this help:

Inside js/utils.js define functions:

```js
function loadFileSync(fileName) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', fileName, false);
    req.send(null);

    if (req.status === 200) {
        //console.log(req.responseText);
        return req.responseText
    } else 
        return "ERROR!!!"
}

function includeFile(fileName) {
    document.write(loadFileSync(fileName))
}
```

And in main html file add this:

```
<script src="js/utils.js"></script>

<script> includeFile("navigation.html") </script>
```